# Fitting a quadratic regression in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, polynomial, quadratic-form

I am trying to fit a quadratic regression model in R. Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
dat <- structure(list(heading = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), startingpos = c(8L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
4L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 
4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 
8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 
8L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 
0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 
4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
8L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 
8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 
0L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 
0L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
0L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 
0L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 
8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 
0L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 
0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 
0L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
4L, 4L, 8L), FirstSteeringTime = c(0.4333325988244, 0.33254630198401, 
0.400026140468498, 0.933583287728609, 0.366613128009007, 0.43335584150401, 
0.516691111726999, 0.383459543097199, 0.783127987777988, 0.283220203865, 
0.416811581253, 0.400114583392991, 0.416630167609981, 0.500080141967999, 
0.466509864102989, 0.183366330894984, 0.69996205708, 0.833361757822985, 
0.516727937792041, 0.38330197583997, 0.416698386385008, 0.46657234767099, 
0.433382404566999, 0.416618697195986, 0.399949469809997, 0.733300000000042, 
0.416799999999967, 0.36669999999998, 0.433299999999974, 0.616399999999999, 
0.398599999999988, 0.249961740134204, 0.466699999999946, 0.466800000000035, 
0.7166, 0.483280000000001, 0.383409999999998, 0.399969999999996, 
0.699960000000004, 0.61666, 0.582999999999998, 0.4495, 0.367099999999994, 
0.416699999999992, 0.399999999999977, 0.583399999999983, 0.516499999999979, 
0.449899999999985, 0.383399999999995, 0.282800000000009, 0.566699999999997, 
0.466700000000003, 0.483299999999986, 0.533299999999997, 0.433199999999999, 
0.61650000000003, 0.550000000000011, 0.683300000000031, 0.38330000000002, 
0.449999999999989, 0.433400000000006, 0.449999999999989, 0.399799999999999, 
0.583399999999997, 0.383279999999999, 0.450000000000003, 0.383200000000002, 
0.383399999999995, 0.549999999999983, 0.383299999999991, 0.716399999999993, 
0.566499999999991, 0.400000000000006, 0.616600000000005, 0.733399999999989, 
0.449899999999985, 0.566699999999997, 0.5, 0.600099999999998, 
0.5, 0.483439999999998, 0.483400000000017, 0.54989999999998, 
0.666699999999992, 0.716499999999996, 0.583300000000001, 0.433199999999999, 
0.633299999999963, 0.516599999999983, 0.499859999999998, 0.483400000000017, 
0.500099999999975, 0.416699999999992, 0.333399999999983, 0.483300000000042, 
0.550000000000011, 0.383319999999998, 0.599970000000001, 0.5, 
0.399969999999996, 0.483379999999997, 0.399969999999996, 0.683300000000003, 
0.599999999999994, 0.583400000000012, 0.566699999999997, 0.516099999999994, 
0.38330000000002, 0.383399999999995, 0.466100000000012, 0.800000000000011, 
0.616700000000009, 0.16670000000002, 0.599999999999994, 0.533299999999997, 
0.550100000000043, 0.38330000000002, 0.400000000000034, 0.466700000000003, 
0.666799999999967, 0.583399999999983, 0.716600000000028, 0.599899999999991, 
0.466600000000028, 0.599999999999966, 0.5, 0.449900000000014, 
0.550099999999986, 0.5, 0.583329999999997, 0.333350000000003, 
0.39996, 0.433340000000001, 0.450100000000006, 0.466790000000003, 
0.566599999999994, 0.666700000000006, 0.566099999999992, 0.383399999999995, 
0.433290000000003, 0.41640000000001, 0.350100000000026, 0.566699999999997, 
0.316900000000032, 0.400109999999998, 0.399900000000002, 0.333300000000008, 
0.45010000000002, 0.566800000000001, 0.433499999999981, 0.483299999999986, 
0.366199999999992, 0.433399999999949, 0.699999999999989, 0.45010000000002, 
0.333499999999958, 0.38344, 0.266697979166521, 0.566645063859099, 
0.483681528935506, 0.516593159768306, 0.499657544687992, 0.566733809440009, 
0.533366376472998, 0.549978704078995, 0.700037822520983, 0.616626333711991, 
0.416589265829003, 0.466635434660986, 0.549884525094996, 0.400077758033007, 
1.70000789965499, 0.600099999999998, 0.599900000000019, 0.4666, 
0.583300000000008, 0.483400000000017, 0.483400000000017, 0.516699999999958, 
0.433400000000006, 0.566800000000001, 0.483400000000017, 0.533299999999997, 
0.566700000000026, 0.500099999999975, 0.533400000000029, 0.566700000000026, 
0.466700000000003, 0.666700000000048, 0.61669999999998, 0.44997, 
0.5167, 0.732889999999998, 0.516690000000001, 0.516800000000003, 
0.700000000000003, 0.433400000000006, 0.4161, 0.666599999999988, 
0.583300000000008, 0.466699999999999, 0.433300000000003, 0.433500000000009, 
0.466499999999996, 0.483399999999989, 0.516600000000011, 0.516899999999993, 
0.61669999999998, 0.599999999999994, 0.533500000000004, 0.399999999999999, 
0.550000000000011, 0.550099999999986, 0.566700000000026, 0.5, 
0.566800000000001, 0.816599999999994, 0.516599999999983, 0.399499999999989, 
0.532940000000004, 0.583300000000008, 0.5, 0.466599999999971, 
0.5, 0.650000000000034, 0.383309999999994, 0.533330000000007, 
0.483360000000005, 0.616789999999995, 0.5, 0.400099999999995, 
0.5501, 0.599599999999995, 0.433199999999999, 0.483400000000017, 
0.800000000000011, 0.616669999999999, 0.316700000000026, 0.549800000000005, 
0.450000000000017, 0.383400000000023, 0.4666, 0.4666, 0.35004, 
0.4666, 0.483400000000017, 0.499900000000025, 0.416679999999999, 
0.533400000000029, 0.416800000000023, 0.566599999999994, 0.450000000000045, 
0.516599999999983, 0.550000000000011, 0.816700000000026, 0.400010000000002, 
0.316699999999969, 0.516399999999976, 0.433259999999997, 0.733278, 
0.55003, 0.483340000000013, 0.783349999999999, 0.533460000000005, 
0.566699999999997, 0.716700000000003, 0.716700000000003, 0.516599999999983, 
0.433399999999978, 0.533299999999997, 0.666699999999992, 0.433299999999974, 
0.516699999999986, 0.466639999999998, 0.650000000000006, 0.566300000000012, 
0.416699999999992, 0.416600000000017, 0.349899999999991, 0.449999999999989, 
0.483290000000004, 0.733200000000011, 0.466700000000003, 0.583300000000008, 
0.38330000000002, 0.483299999999986, 0.816600000000001, 0.433400000000006, 
0.550000000000011, 0.616100000000017, 0.483299999999986, 0.583330000000004, 
0.449950000000001, 0.566629999999989, 0.483359999999999, 0.816699999999997, 
0.783299999999997, 0.5334, 0.299900000000008, 0.400100000000009, 
0.600099999999998, 0.500100000000003, 0.449900000000014, 0.63330000000002, 
0.533199999999994, 0.683399999999978, 0.516799999999989, 0.566599999999994, 
0.650100000000009, 0.883369999999999, 0.399999999999977, 0.433300000000031, 
0.54989999999998, 0.45010000000002, 0.466600000000028, 0.383399999999995, 
0.63330000000002, 0.549909999999997, 0.233300000000042, 0.633299999999963, 
0.466700000000003, 0.632779999999997, 0.48338460869733, 0.583214904951404, 
0.466673227015406, 0.416451543573601, 0.36661533093141, 0.583078163940002, 
0.616621669918999, 0.533258553406995, 0.500063088017015, 0.433389619515992, 
0.549822629098003, 0.449958223055006, 0.516826992736014, 0.532235259741014, 
0.48334687662998, 0.483007589880998, 0.599507007900996, 0.549939447577998, 
0.400010323494001, 0.83332719558399, 0.466675340011989, 0.516813107334997, 
0.833300000000008, 0.533299999999997, 0.550099999999986, 0.516699999999958, 
0.466599999999971, 0.533299999999997, 0.498899999999992, 0.483300000000042, 
0.600000000000023, 0.466600000000028, 0.483399999999961, 0.466700000000003, 
0.683299999999974, 0.333349, 0.416550000000001, 0.516599999999997, 
0.566729999999993, 0.416650000000004, 0.583269999999999, 0.54965, 
0.399899999999988, 0.500099999999989, 0.682200000000009, 0.29989999999998, 
0.46669, 0.633499999999998, 0.316800000000001, 0.449999999999989, 
0.350070000000002, 0.683399999999978, 0.4666, 0.5, 0.616800000000012, 
0.449999999999989, 0.483399999999961, 0.683399999999949, 0.649999999999977, 
0.433199999999999, 0.583300000000008, 0.599899999999991, 0.516599999999983, 
0.449999999999989, 0.833399999999983, 0.599899999999991, 0.61562, 
0.600099999999998, 0.433499999999981, 0.433400000000006, 0.466679999999997, 
0.516559999999998, 0.516640000000002, 0.566780000000008, 0.533420000000007, 
0.51671, 0.4833, 0.465599999999995, 0.416700000000006, 0.449949999999998, 
0.650099999999981, 0.383299999999991, 0.416600000000017, 0.399999999999999, 
0.566800000000001, 0.800000000000011, 0.350099999999998, 0.5822, 
0.550000000000011, 0.433400000000006, 0.483200000000011, 0.366700000000037, 
0.316699999999969, 0.45010000000002, 0.45010000000002, 0.649999999999977, 
0.466769999999997, 0.516599999999983, 0.600099999999998, 0.499899999999968, 
0.549800000000005, 0.583300000000008, 0.400009999999995, 0.49995, 
0.48319, 0.516689999999997, 0.432280000000006, 0.400030000000001, 
0.500020000000006, 0.38336000000001, 0.53308, 0.533500000000004, 
0.666600000000017, 0.516700000000014, 0.366700000000009, 0.650020000000001, 
0.38330000000002, 0.616700000000009, 0.483399999999989, 0.45010000000002, 
0.66670000000002, 0.449900000000014, 0.483299999999986, 0.783299999999997, 
0.399999999999977, 0.366669999999999, 0.400100000000009, 0.800000000000011, 
0.38349999999997, 0.433369999999996, 0.399900000000002, 0.383299999999998, 
0.350099999999998, 0.450099999999964, 0.366499999999974, 0.550099999999986, 
0.416600000000017, 0.450049999999997, 0.516333, 0.449950000000001, 
0.550070000000005, 0.400019999999998, 0.383349999999993, 0.516569999999987, 
0.599890000000002, 0.533349999999999, 0.549999999999997, 0.482399999999998, 
0.416799999999995, 0.649100000000004, 0.449999999999989, 0.5334, 
0.450000000000017, 0.383399999999995, 0.515500000000003, 0.733500000000021, 
0.41670000000002, 0.75, 0.649999999999977, 0.633399999999995, 
0.51662, 0.36669999999998, 0.483299999999986, 0.466700000000003, 
0.483100000000007, 0.45010000000002, 0.416600000000017, 0.399999999999977, 
0.533299999999997, 0.533299999999997, 0.382300000000001, 0.533299999999997, 
0.516600000000039, 0.448603033908896, 0.349815655656002, 0.383307041550012, 
0.399893806548988, 0.383485741159006), pNum = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L
)), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've read online many ways to fit a quadratic regression. Some examples include:

```
m1 <- glmer(formula = FirstSteeringTime ~ stats::poly(startingpos, 2) + (1 |pNum),
            family = Gamma(link = "identity"),
            data = dat)

m2 <- glmer(formula = FirstSteeringTime ~ startingpos^2 + (1 | pNum),
            family = Gamma(link = "identity"),
            data = dat)
```

However I am yet to find a consensus. Are these 2 models equivalent? The output I get is very similar so I imagine they are doing very similar things?

Also side note: when I run a summary on the first model (m1) I get the following output:

```
    AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  -777.2   -756.1    393.6   -787.2      495 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7497 -0.6122 -0.1233  0.5585 10.3273 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 pNum     (Intercept) 0.0003794 0.01948 
 Residual             0.0547070 0.23390 
Number of obs: 500, groups:  pNum, 4

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   0.49196    0.03562  13.810  < 2e-16 ***
stats::poly(startingpos, 2)1 -0.79182    0.11437  -6.923 4.41e-12 ***
stats::poly(startingpos, 2)2  0.35565    0.10966   3.243  0.00118 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) s::(,2)1
stts::(,2)1 -0.018         
stts::(,2)2  0.058 -0.103
```

What is the difference between stats::poly(startingpos, 2)1 and stats::poly(startingpos, 2)2?

Any help is most appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function `poly()` in R is used to construct orthogonal polynomials. These are equivalent to standard polynomials but are numerically more stable. That is, the two models

```
m1 <- glmer(FirstSteeringTime ~ poly(startingpos, 2) + (1 | pNum), 
            family = Gamma(link = "identity"), data = data)
```

and

```
m2 <- glmer(FirstSteeringTime ~ startingpos + I(startingpos^2) + (1 | pNum), 
            family = Gamma(link = "identity"), data = data)
```

are equivalent, but `m1` is preferable.

From both models, you will get the corresponding terms for the linear and quadratic terms for `startingpos`. For both simple and orthogonal polynomials, the interpretation of these coefficients is not straighforward. That is, you cannot interpret one of them in isolation. What you could perhaps look at is the magnitude and statistical significance of the second coefficient. This would tell you if you simplify the model and only use the linear term.

Comment: +1. Just as an observation, OPs second model will only include the linear term, afaik. Without the `I()`, R will ignore the `^2`, I think.

Comment: @COOL That's an excellent observation.  Because `^` is one of the "symbolic" operators used by `formula`, it will not be interpreted numerically without the protection by `I`.  It's not that `R` "ignores" it, though: it interprets it as a "crossing" of its argument with itself.  That's why you get no error message or warning.